# How to enable the level 3 key on a keypress on IBUS keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, ibus

I am writing a m17n ibus regional language keyboard. I want my keys to have different chars for 3rd(AltGr) and 4th level of key press. I tried following the **pa-jhelum** keyboard, however my keyboard doesn't print anything even after assigning it in same format of the other keyboards.

However, if I select the **pa-jhelum** keyboard, I am able to access the 3rd and 4th level access keys for that,

Am I missing something or something needs to be enabled to use AltGr.

Comment: I don't know anything about creating input methods, but if you look at the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/in` file, the trick used in the corresponding XKB layouts to enable AltGr is the line: `include "level3(ralt_switch)"`

Comment: Actually I am looking for a ibus keyboard setting, not the XKB keyboard.

Comment: It was meant as a hint, which I hoped was useful. Maybe not. There is always the possibility to open _Tweaks_ and enable AltGr via _Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Key to choose the 3rd level_. But that's not exactly what you ask for either, I suppose.